# Civicrm export paricipamts resulting in SQL error

Tags: civicrm

I am using Drupal 6 with Civicrm 3.4. While exporting Prtimary fields of  participants from civicrm 3.4, I am getting SQL error "Can not join more than 61 tables". I am having more custom tables. How can i resolve this issue without cutting the custom tables. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of MySQL itself, and not an issue with CiviCRM. You could do multiple exports of subsets of the custom data then assemble it in Excel.